# Updating Jlist dynamically

Tags: java, swing, jlist

I am new to swing. I have dragged and drop the Jlist component in panel. It generated code that is

```
jList1 = new javax.swing.JList();
jList1.setModel(new javax.swing.AbstractListModel() {
    String[] strings = {"Item 1", "Item 2", "Item 3", "Item 4", "Item 5"};

    public int getSize() {
        return strings.length;
    }

    public Object getElementAt(int i) {
        return strings[i];
    }
});
jScrollPane1.setViewportView(jList1);
```

After executing the code it gives the element which are included by default.
I want to insert the element dynamically through code, how can I do that. I tried using

```
DefaultListModel model = new DefaultListModel();
jList1 = new JList(model);
for (int i = 0; i < 15; i++) {
    model.addElement("Element " + i);
}
jList1.setModel(model);
```

But the list does not get updated. How can I update it dynamically.

Answer (score 6):

Start by getting rid of `jList1 = new JList(model);` after you create new `DefaultListModel`

```
DefaultListModel model = new DefaultListModel();
//jList1 = new JList(model);
for (int i = 0; i < 15; i++) {
    model.addElement("Element " + i);
}
jList1.setModel(model);
```

You're creating a new instance of `JList` which has nothing to do with the instance that is on the screen

Comment: After getting rid of jList1 = new JList(model); It is giving me null pointer exception error.

Comment: Consider providing a [runnable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) which demonstrates your problem. This will result in less confusion and better responses - And make sure that `initComponents` is called first

Comment: Thank you I had called the initComponents at last and there by it was giving me null pointer exception . now the code is working ...

Answer (score 1):

No to add element Dynamically you may use given code

```java
  DefaultListModel model = (DefaultListModel)jList1.getModel();
  model.addElement("Element " + count++);
```

Comment: The model still contains the defaults values supplied by NetBeans, I would assume, based on what  the OP seems to be trying to do, they want to clear the mode first.  I'd also argue that, unless you are careful, up casting isn't always a good idea ;)